# CakePHP model SQL queries conditions parameter

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a long query like this:

```
$a=$this->Signin->find('all',
    array(
        'fields'=> array(
            .....
        ),
        'conditions' => array('mytable.user_type ...),
        'order' => ....
        'limit' => ....
));
```

**user_type** column can take values of 0 or 1.
I have a function parameter `$type`, regarding to this parameter, I need to change my SQL query. Regarding to `$type` I will query for

- "mytable.user_type"=1,
- "mytable.user_type"=0,
- "mytable.user_type"=1 OR "mytable.user_type=0

I don't want to write same query three times. I want to change only **conditions** part. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can define **$type** as an array and manage the values in $type

Like for multiple values

```
$type = array(1,0);
'conditions' => array('mytable.user_type'=>$type)
```

for single value

```
$type = array(1);
'conditions' => array('mytable.user_type'=>$type)
```

Hence you just need to manipulate $type as per condition, Hope this work

Comment: That's cool solution. Because of other limitations it seems like I will change this query to native SQL query. I would be very happy if you can propose me a similar solution for native query. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$user_type = ($type == 'something') ? 1 : 0 ;
```

then, in your conditions:

```
'conditions' => array('mytable.user_type' => $user_type);
```

given that user_type can take only two values, your third query (`"mytable.user_type"=1 OR "mytable.user_type=0`) is unnecessary

**EDIT :**

```
if($type == 'conditions_where_usertype_is_necessary') $user_type = ($type == 'something') ? 1 : 0 ;
```

then, for your conditions:

```
if( isset($user_type) ) {
    $options['conditions']['mytable.user_type'] = $user_type;
}
$options['conditions']['other_conditions'] = ...;
$this->Signin->find('all', $options);
```

Comment: Third option needs all rows where user_type=1 or user_type=0. In that condition query won't check for user_type column.